# Make Hibernate treat detached objects as same instance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, persistence

I have a many to many relationship between two tables. I first fill parent objects with child objects and vice versa. When I stumble upon a new, before unseen child object, I add it to a hash map, and connect the parent and child with their collections as needed. Every iteration I check if the child already exists in the map, and if It doesn't, I create it and add it to the map, and then of course connect the child and parent with their collections. However, at the end, when I persist all of the parents, the children get persisted as many times it is referenced by the parent objects, I get duplicates in child table. How could I tell Hibernate that these duplicates are one and the same object?

One solution would be to persist every new, before unseen child, so I could get Its id and based on that Hibernate would now that this is the same object. But can this be achieved without in between persist commands, that is, to call persist (on parent objects) only at the end, when all mappings are set?

Comment: If you are maintaining a map, are you not able to look up the instance from the map and reuse it rather then have multiple copies?  JPA requires throwing an exception if you call persist on two instances with the same identity, so I don't think you'll find a way to avoid this error using JPA methods.

Comment: I don't get an error, just duplicate values. The problem is, im am calling unique objects from the map, but since im persisting at the end of processing, the objects in the map don't have id specified yet.

Comment: JPA has no way of telling that they are the same if they don't have identity.  You will have to manage it yourself.

Comment: Does that mean I'll have to persist it, or can I just generate an id for the objects and not use the generated ids? Would that work?

Comment: It means you either have to figure out what makes two instances the same despite not having an ID, or find a way to assign IDs.  You are able to use your own method of sequencing rather than use generated Ids, or call persist (and likely flush to have IDs assigned, depending on the generation strategy)

Comment: I know what makes two instances the same (which property), but how can this help?

Comment: You can use this to find your equivalent entity within your map, allowing you to reuse a single instance throughout your model rather then duplicating it.  This will cause there to be only a single instance for that dataset, so only a single insert.

Comment: This is what i tried, but doesn't work, because when persisting duplicates are generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73194/discussion-between-chris-and-user2340939).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is, instead of a map, use separate collections for the parent and child objects. After that I just persisted the parent object collection and that was It (because child object can't exist without a parent object, but parent can without child objects, otherwise I could also instead persist the child objects).

So the problem with map was, that although you add a value to a specific keys collection values from another keys collection values, It does not reference the same object, i.e. It creates a new one for the other key collection, which is why in this case you get duplicates when persisting the key values (which are the parent objects).